# How to append data in .dat file using C language in ubuntu?

Tags: c

Here is the code in which i m getting error....

```
for (i=0; i<portcount; i++)
{   
    printf("%f ", ccds[i]/100000);
    fp=fopen("/administrator/IDS/et.dat", "a");
    //fprintf(fp, "er");        
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", (int)ccds[i]/100000);
    fclose(fp); 
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly ?

Comment: Comment to the code itself: It would be better to open before the loop and to close afterwards. That would reduce overhead.

Comment: please update your question title to the problem that you are facing since your code snippet looks ok. What is the problem. mention it. Have you created the file in the code as well ? Also, have you tried with a different file extension like say, *.txt ? try different things. There seems to be some silly mistake here.

Comment: Newly captured data is not entered in .dat file...

Comment: @user1457874 edit the question, dont add it to the comment here

Answer (score 6):

You should check that the file actually opens successfully, and probably also put the file open/close *outside* the loop:

```
fp = fopen("/administrator/IDS/et.dat", "a");
if (fp == NULL)             // always check for success when opening a file
{
    perror("fopen failed");
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < portcount; i++)
    {   
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", (int)ccds[i]/100000);
    }
    fclose(fp); 
}
```

Comment: Append ("a") mode always writes to the end of file, seeking is not needed.

Comment: @interjay: thanks - I never knew that ! I'll update the answer.